In a Python plotly bar chart, can I toggle discrete x-axis items in addition to a legend?
I have a plot like this that shows 'Metrics' across different 'Regions':

I can filter regions by clicking on the legend, and I can switch to showing individual metrics using the dropdown menu.
What I want: Instead of the dropdown, I want something that behaves more like checkboxes, to filter out or show specific combinations of metrics. In this way, both the regions and the metrics are interactively toggleable. Is this possible?
This is my code so far:
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd

# Example data
data = {
    "Metric": ["Metric A", "Metric B", "Metric C", "Metric D", "Metric E"],
    "Region 1": [5, 15, 25, 10, 20],
    "Region 2": [10, 25, 5, 15, 30],
    "Region 3": [20, 10, 15, 30, 5]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Create an initial figure with all regions
fig = go.Figure()

regions = df.columns[1:]
for region in regions:
    fig.add_trace(go.Bar(
        x=df["Metric"],
        y=df[region],
        name=region
    ))

# Add dropdown menus to filter metrics
metric_options = [{"label": metric, "method": "update", "args": [{"x": [df["Metric"]], "y": [df[region] for region in regions]}]} for metric in df["Metric"]]

dropdown_buttons = [
    {
        "label": "All Metrics",
        "method": "update",
        "args": [{"x": [df["Metric"]], "y": [df[region] for region in regions]}]
    }
]

for metric in df["Metric"]:
    y_values = [df[region][df["Metric"] == metric].values[0] for region in regions]
    dropdown_buttons.append({
        "label": metric,
        "method": "update",
        "args": [{"x": [[metric] * len(regions)], "y": [y_values]}]
    })

fig.update_layout(
    updatemenus=[
        {
            "buttons": dropdown_buttons,
            "direction": "down",
            "showactive": True,
            "x": 1.15,
            "xanchor": "left",
            "y": 1.2,
            "yanchor": "top"
        }
    ],
    title="Interactive Bar Chart with Filters",
    xaxis_title="Metrics",
    yaxis_title="Values"
)

# Save as HTML
fig.write_html("interactive_bar_chart.html")

